# syntax error unexpected string

Tags: string, syntax-error

I have difficulty to solve this string problem

```
contentString = '<div id="infoHead">Drag me for new coordinates.</br></div>'+results[1].formatted_address+'<div id="latlng">'+
                                  'Latitude: '+dmsLat+'</br>'+'Longitude: '+dmsLng+'</div>'+'</br>'+'<a href="//www.youtube.com/embed/Mzja4le8htk"'
            + 'style="width=420px; height=315px"'
            + 'onclick=' + '"window.open(this.href,'rockclimbing','left=400,top=250,width=420,height=315,toolbar=1,resizable=0');return false;"'
            + '>Click here for more details</a>'
```

For example through this code:

```
'"window.open(this.href,'rockclimbing','left=400,top=250,width=420,height=315,toolbar=1,resizable=0');return false;"'
```

it's show some error where `rockclimbing` and start from `left until sizeable=0` cannot put single quatotion.

So how to solve this problem?
I can't provide the link since this is my second project. Any kind of help I'm really appreciated.

Comment: What language is that? And please format code as code; click `{}`, not **B**.

Comment: what is the relation between "I can't provide the link" and "this is my second project"?

Comment: You're using single quotations in your string, which is also wrapped in single quotes. You'll need to add the \ escape character to them for it to work (so `\'rockclimbing\'`, for example)

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the inner quotes:

```
'"window.open(this.href,\'rockclimbing\',\'left=400,top=250,width=420,height=315,toolbar=1,resizable=0\');return false;"'
```

Otherwise the single quote before `rockclimbing` terminates the string.

Comment: So I was wrong!
SO *is* a site where people will fix all your syntax errors for you, for free.

> Teach a man how to fish and you feed him for a life time.

Answer (score 0):

I will show you how to find your errors.

I am only including our example up to the first error.

As you move this piece into your environment this error should go away, provided

```
results[1].formatted_address
```

can be converted to a string.

Move in more and more of your original code as you fix your errors.

Good Luck!

### Code Wrapped in Exception Handler for Error Reporting

```
try {
    contentString = '<div id="infoHead">Drag me for new coordinates.</br></div>'
    +results[1].formatted_address;
} catch(exception) {
    console.log(exception.stack);
}
```

### Console Log Output for Error Diagnosis

```
ReferenceError: results is not defined
    at <anonymous>:2:84
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (<anonymous>:580:39)
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (<anonymous>:539:52)
    at Object.InjectedScript.evaluate (<anonymous>:458:21)
```